# Bluetooth not discovering any devices on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth

I'm unable to discover any devices using bluetooth , also all though I make my laptop visible it's undiscoverable by other devices.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.1, on a asus x556ua laptop.

Here is the output of:

```
lspci | grep Net; lsusb


03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless    Network Adapter (rev 01)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:3018 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5a01 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And also the output of:

```
    dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.542044] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.542056] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.542058] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.542060] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.542064] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.548307] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.548310] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.548311] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.548312] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.548313] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.548314] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.548338] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.548351] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    3.548352] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    4.101503] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.101506] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.101509] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.511101] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.511109] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.511113] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

---

### UPDATE

I'm including the outputs you asked for:

```
usb-devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=12
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-57-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=24ae ProdID=1100 Rev=01.10
S:  Manufacturer=RAPOO
S:  Product=Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=04 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=0129 Rev=39.60
S:  Manufacturer=Generic
S:  Product=USB2.0-CRW
S:  SerialNumber=20100201396000000
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=rtsx_usb

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=05 Cnt=03 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=13d3 ProdID=5a01 Rev=16.08
S:  Manufacturer=Azurewave
S:  Product=USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
S:  SerialNumber=0x0001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=07 Cnt=04 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04ca ProdID=3018 Rev=00.01
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-57-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

and also the output of:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:1823]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

I have also filed the bug report as you told me with the added output of:

```
usb-devices | awk '/3018/' RS=
```

The link to the bug report is:

bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1653843

Thank you for your time.

---

### UPDATE

Hello again , I have installed the module as you explained to me in the launchpad bug report, but now the bluetooth device appears as disabled.

As per your request here is the output you asked for in the launchpad bug report:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.287544] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.287559] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.287562] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.287565] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.287570] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.293584] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.293586] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.293588] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.293589] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.293590] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.293591] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.293618] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.293631] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    3.293632] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    5.076376] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.076379] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.076383] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices` terminal command.

Comment: And also `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This device is not supported by Linux kernel. The issue can be fixed if you file a bug report to Launchpad.

Run in a terminal `ubuntu-bug linux`, then follow directions in your browser.

Add to the bug report the output of

```
usb-devices | awk '/3018/' RS=
```

command.

Drop a link to the bug report here, so I can find it.

I can add the device to the driver list and build a test module for you. After that the BT device should work. Then it will be added to mainline kernel code.

[This deb package](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-lp1653843-dkms_0.2_all.deb) should fix it temporarily. **Only for the 4.4 kernel!**

I've sent an upstream patch. Ubuntu stable kernels should get it later.

Comment: I did as you told me.  The link to the bug is : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1653843

Comment: See the bug report. I created a test module.

Comment: Hello , I installed the test module , but it didn't work, I re-edited the question with the requested output and also added it in the launchpad bug report.

Comment: I've rebuilt the module. My bad.

Comment: The new module solved the problem , I was able to detect , pair and connect to an iphone through bluetooth , I was unable though to pair from the iphone to the laptop all though the laptop was visible, I need to test further with another phone , maybe that iphone was somewhat faulty. Anyway the new module seems to have solved the problem fully, I'll update further when I'm able to pair to the laptop from another device. Thank you for your efforts. Will this fix be inputed in the newest kernel, meaning that next versions of ubuntu won't have this problem?